# Function "length" not working properly in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made function in the google sheet

```
function AVG_ZERO(input) {
  return input.length
};
```

But length of array different
If the range of numbers is located in a column, then it is considered correct
If the range of numbers is located in a string, then the length is 1
Links to images:
https://postimg.cc/56xfmhZh
https://postimg.cc/HVc13T6P

Comment: If the range is A1:A3 for example the  array length is 3 (rows) if its D1:F1 its 1 (row).  What is your function supposed to do?  Or diagrammatically [[A1],[A2],[A3]] vs [[D1,E1,F1]];

Answer (score 0):

Try unfolding the array by using the [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function into separate elements regardless of the orientation:

```
function AVG_ZERO(input) {
  return input.flat().length
};
```

That will give you 3 for both row and column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

If you pass a range of cells as an argument of a custom function, the argument will be treated by your custom function as a two-dimensional array of the cell's values, with the inner arrays being the individual rows. That is, the outer array `length` will equal the number of rows in your range: 1 for `B1:D1` and 3 for `B1:B3`.

#### Reference:

- [Custom functions: Arguments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments)